# How do SVG's and HTML's width/height attributes on foreignObject, img and svg elements relate?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG with HTML in a `foreignObject` element. This SVG will be included on a webpage with an `img` element, as usual.

**How do all those `height` and `width` attributes relate?** They can be set (or not) on:

- the `img` element of the webpage
- the `svg` root element in the SVG image file
- the `foreignObject` element in the SVG image file under the `svg` root element

Answer (score 0):

- outer dimension of the image in the website, where embedded with `img`:

  - if the `img` comes with height and width attributes, they determine the outer dimensions, like with normal bitmaps
  - if the `img` has no constraints on size, the SVG file is consulted for it's size, like with normal bitmaps

    - if the SVG root element has absolute height and width, that is the size of the SVG
  - if height and width of the `svg` root element are 100% (i.e. relative) or not set at all, the browser makes it 300x150
- scaling of the SVG in the webpage:

  - if the SVG (via absolute height/width in the root element) has a size different than what the `img` in the webpage has, the SVG is *scaled*, like with bitmaps
  - if the SVG doesn't have absolute dimensions, the SVG is *not scaled*, but *clipped* if rendering of it in the space allotted is not possible
- and the `foreignObject`?

  - width and height are required attributes
  - unlike the `svg` element, `foreignObject` does not get 100% width and height by default
  - but %-units can be specified "manually"
  - if the HTML in the SVG should fill the image entirely, specify 100% height/width

Comment: This is all correct for SVG 1.1. SVG 2 has slightly different rules. e.g. width/height on foreignObject will become optional.

Comment: @RobertLongson Any insights on SVG 2? How does the foreignObject without width/height behave?